# Problem reading and posting message to IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have 2 different IBM MQ Hosts and thus 2 different channels, managers, and request/reply queues in my Spring Boot application. From my local and legacy Tomcat servers everything seems to work fine, but when we deploy to Azure cloud it shows connection to IBM MQ successful but unable to listen to the queue or put message on the queues. I don't see any errors as well.

My IBM MQ configuration looks like this (I have 2 host configured, I am just providing one here as both are similar):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
        
        <bean id="MFmqConnectionFactoryOne" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
          <property name="hostName" value="${MQHost1}" /> 
          <property name="port" value="${MQPort1}" /> 
          <property name="channel" value="${MQChannel1}" /> 
          <property name="queueManager" value="${MQManager1}" /> 
          <property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true" /> 
          <property name="failIfQuiesce" value="1" /> 
          <property name="transportType" value="1" />
         </bean>            
         <bean id="MFConnectionFactory1"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="MFmqConnectionFactoryOne" />
            <property name="username" value ="${MQUser}"/>
            <property name="password" value=""/>
        </bean>     
        <bean id="queue.mainframeRequest1" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="MFConnectionFactory1">
            <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${MQManager1}" />
            <property name="baseQueueName" value="${requestMQName1}" />
            <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="queue.mainframeRequest2" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="MFConnectionFactory1">
            <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${MQManager1}" />
            <property name="baseQueueName" value="${requestMQName2}" />
            <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="queue.mainframeResponse1" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="MFConnectionFactory1">
            <!-- For cluster environment with Mainframe, Qmgr is no needed -->
            <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${MQManager1}" /> 
            <property name="baseQueueName" value="${responseMQName1}" />
            <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
            <property name="persistence" value="${persistenceFlag}"/>
            <property name="expiry" value="${expiryMilliSeconds}"/>         
        </bean>     
        <bean id="queue.mainframeResponse2" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="MFConnectionFactory1">
            <!-- For cluster environment with Mainframe, Qmgr is no needed -->
            <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${MQManager1}" /> 
            <property name="baseQueueName" value="${responseMQName2}" />
            <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
            <property name="persistence" value="${persistenceFlag}"/>
            <property name="expiry" value="${expiryMilliSeconds}"/>
        </bean>     
        <bean id="jmsTransactionManager1" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="MFConnectionFactory1" />
        </bean>     
        <!-- A POJO that implements the JMS message listener -->
        <bean id="messageListener1" class="ListenerClass"/>
        <bean id="messageListener2" class="ListenerClass" />        
        <bean id="expenseDestinationResolver1" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.BeanFactoryDestinationResolver"/>
        <!-- The Spring message listener container configuration -->         
        <jms:listener-container
              container-type="default"
              connection-factory="MFConnectionFactory1"         
              acknowledge="transacted"
               concurrency="15-30"
               transaction-manager="jmsTransactionManager1"
              destination-resolver = "expenseDestinationResolver1"
              >
            <jms:listener destination="queue.mainframeRequest1" ref="messageListener1" method="onMessage" /> 
            <jms:listener destination="queue.mainframeRequest2" ref="messageListener2" method="onMessage" />
        </jms:listener-container>               
        <util:list id="processCategories1" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>ONLINE</value>
            <value>BATCH</value>
        </util:list>            
        <util:map id="categoryJmsTemplateMap1" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="ONLINE" value-ref="jmsResponseTemplate1" />
            <entry key="BATCH" value-ref="jmsResponseTemplate2" />
        </util:map>     
        <bean id="routingConfiguration1" class="JMSConfiguration">
            <property name="processCategories" ref="processCategories1" />
            <property name="templateMap" ref="categoryJmsTemplateMap1" />
        </bean>     
        <bean id="jmsResponseTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
            p:connectionFactory-ref="MFConnectionFactory1"
            p:defaultDestination-ref="queue.mainframeResponse1" />
        <bean id="jmsResponseTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
            p:connectionFactory-ref="MFConnectionFactory1"
            p:defaultDestination-ref="queue.mainframeResponse2" />  
</beans>
```

I have the firewall ports open. Any suggestions what I must be missing or doing wrong? I am confused because this does seem to be working just fine locally and also on legacy Tomcat.

Comment: What error do you get?  What makes you think it is connected, can you see the channel running from your azure IP if you display channel status on the queue manager?

Comment: I am checking the connection using the connectionFactory like below:


@Autowired
private UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter MFConnectionFactory1;
MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) MFConnectionFactory1.createConnection();
if (connection != null) {
 connection.start();
 neoLogger.information("IBM MQ connection is valid", "");
 super.setStatus(MonitorConstants.STATUS_GREEN);
Can you please suggest if there is any other way to check the connection between application and the MQ channel

Comment: Use an MQ admin tool (runmqsc, MQ Explorer, Console, ....) to view both channel status and application connections to determine whether your application has connected correctly. If it works in other environments, then it is clearly something about this environment. It is unlikely we can tell what that is from your config, we need to see runtime status such as the ones I mention. Especially if you have not received any non-zero reason codes.

Comment: I can see the instance of my application connected to the mq channel.

Comment: Do the DISPLAY CONNECTION output where you see the instance of your application connecting in over the SVRCONN channel also show that your connection has a queue open? Use DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) to see the handles as well as the connections.